# Presheaves over subcanonical sites

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

By definition, [every representable presheaf over a subcanonical site is a sheaf](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subcanonical+coverage#definition). Also, we know that [every presheaf is a colimit of representables](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/presheaf#properties_of_presheaves_4). How does this not imply that every presheaf over a subcanonical site is a sheaf, given how Grothendieck topoi are cocomplete ?

Comment: The colimit of sheaves is in general not the colimit of the underlying presheaves.